# Transactional SELECT and INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the following table, records are stored of volume license agreements 
purchased by customers. The `TotalLicenses` column stores the maximum number of
users that are allowed to be activated with that license.

**VolumeLicenses**

```
+-----------+---------------+
| LicenseId | TotalLicenses |
+-----------+---------------+
|       901 |             3 |
|       902 |           100 |
|       903 |           150 |
+-----------+---------------+
```

Another table stores the users who have activated with each license:

**VolumeLicenseUsers**

```
+-----------+--------+
| LicenseId | UserId |
+-----------+--------+
|       901 | fred   |
|       901 | bob    |
|       901 | donna  |
|       902 | matt   |
|       902 | sarah  |
+-----------+--------+
```

In the example above, I should not be able to INSERT another record with a 
`LicenseId` of 901, because the maximum number (3) has already been reached. I 
should, however, be able to INSERT additional records with `LicenseId` of 902 
until there are 100 such records in the table.

To do so reliably, it seems that I would have to check how many licenses are in 
available and in use (by SELECTing on the `VolumeLicenses` and 
`VolumeLicenseUsers` tables), then do the INSERT as long as nothing changes in 
the meantime.

What SQL can I use to make this transactional? Ideally, I would only lock the 
single row in `VolumeLicenses` of that `LicenseId` and only protect the
`VolumeLicenseUsers` table against additional INSERTS with the `LicenseId` in 
question.

**CLARIFICATION**

I am not attempting to enforce database integrity in general, like a pseudo-CHECK CONSTRAINT. I am only looking for some SQL that will allow me to do this without failing to some race condition.

Comment: You need triggers for this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Can you provide an example of how triggers would solve this problem? I tend to avoid triggers religiously, but am willing to go there if that's the best option. I'm not seeing how they help here, though.

Comment: @DaveMateer - If you can guarantee that all data modifications against `VolumeLicenses` or  `VolumeLicenseUsers` go through a particular code path (as seems to be the assumption in your self answer) they won't help but otherwise there is nothing enforcing your desired logic - someone can run an insert or update statement manually that violates this.

Comment: @MartinSmith - OK, I see what you are saying. I added a clarification to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answering my own question, but not 100% sure this is valid, 
transactionally-speaking....*

```
DECLARE @UserId nvarchar(50) = 'john'
DECLARE @LicenseId int = 902

INSERT INTO dbo.VolumeLicenseUsers (LicenseId, UserId)
SELECT l.LicenseId, @UserId
FROM
    dbo.VolumeLicenses l 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.VolumeLicenseUsers u ON u.LicenseId = l.LicenseId
WHERE l.LicenseId = @LicenseId
GROUP BY l.LicenseId, l.TotalLicenses
HAVING COUNT(u.UserId) < l.TotalLicenses

-- Did it work?
SELECT * FROM dbo.VolumeLicenseUsers 
WHERE LicenseId = @LicenseId AND UserId = @UserId
```

Comment: This would need to be run at serializable isolation level to avoid race conditions. Also how are you handling updates/deletes from VolumeLicenses

Comment: Thanks, @MartinSmith. That makes sense. At this point, I am only concerned that my application does the right thing, and am not trying to enforce the integrity of the relationship between the tables in general. I imagine an UPDATE would have to do something similar (at least, when decreasing `TotalLicenses`), and I would use a foreign constraint to enforce a delete.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's actually a clean solution:

`1)` Open a transaction

`2)` Add a record in `VolumeLicenseUsers`

`3)` Check in `VolumeLicenseUsers` if you have more licenses than the number allowed

`4)` If `not 3)` then `commit` else `rollback`

Could it work?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably cleaner solutions, but if you do this:

```
 BEGIN TRANSACTION

 UPDATE VolumeLicenses SET TotalLicenses  = TotalLicenses WHERE LicenseId = 901

 IF ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VolumeLicenseUsers WHERE LicenseId = 901 ) <  ( SELECT TotalLicenses FROM VolumeLicenses WHERE LicenseId = 901 )
 BEGIN
      INSERT INTO VolumeLicenseUsers ( LicenseId,  UserId ) VALUES ( 901, 'John' )
      COMMIT TRANSACTION
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
      --Add your Error Handing here
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
 END
```

The very first update, although it accomplishes nothing will put a row lock on the Volume License to prevent any other calls from running the same logic until either the transaction is rolled back or commited.  This allows you to insert into VolumeLicenseUsers if you have empty licenses without worrying about another transaction doing the same, because a subsequent call to this would be blocked at the first update clause.